# how to keep session active in wcf service c#

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I created wcf service and hosted using windows service, and consuming in my application, after some time when try to consume wcf service not able to connect if I restart wcf service then its works  fine. Is there any way we can keep wcf session alive even though we are not consuming service everytime.

Comment: Please post your service and client config.   I suspect it is just a matter of increasing the timeout

Comment: By session, do you mean the client channel staying active? The session is a different concept in WCF which creates affinity between a consumer and a specific service instance.